# Why is catch block called twice in Grpc Interceptor C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling, grpc, interceptor

I ran into a problem when I started to implement a global error handler for the grpc server service. The problem is that when I get a validation error, I don't want to log it, but I want to return an RpcException with information to the client, and in other Exceptions I log it and return an unhandled error. *The question* is why do I repeatedly get into the catch block **(Exception e)** after I caught the **ValidationException** and **threw the RpcException**? To the fact that it is called twice, the logic I described above breaks down for me.
The implementation is shown below:

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionInterceptor> _logger;

    public ExceptionInterceptor(ILogger<ExceptionInterceptor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context,
        UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        try
        {
            return await continuation(request, context);
        }
        catch (ValidationException e)
        {
            var error = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Errors.Select(p => p.ErrorMessage));
            throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.InvalidArgument, error));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "gRPC Exception");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Interceptor registration:

```
services.AddGrpc(o =>
{
    o.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionInterceptor>();
});
```

Comment: This is a wild guess but what if you move throwing an exception in the `finally` block, not in `catch`? So you catch the error and save the error to a variable defined before try catch, and throw an error in `finally`

Comment: The finally block will not work, then I will have to set the condition in this block for which exception was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that when we register the interceptor globally, it fires twice. If we register it for a specific service, then it works once.The answer is:

```
services.AddGrpc()
    .AddServiceOptions<MyService>(o =>
    {
        o.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionInterceptor>();
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like your options callback was being called for both the default named config, and the named config for your specific service. So you end up adding two interceptors. Feels like a bug in the implementation of `.AddGrpc(options)`

Comment: I registered the interceptor as shown in the Microsoft articles. Most likely you are right.